# Prove any consistent system with coefficient matrix A has exactly $p^{n-rank(A)}$ solutions in $\mathbb{Z_p}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, field-theory

"Prove that in the field $\mathbb{Z_p}$ ($_p$ being a prime), when we have a matrix A that is $m⨯n$. Any consistent system with coefficient matrix A has exactly $p^{n-rank(A)}$ solutions."

I got this question and I can't find the solution to it, I don't even know where to start. Does anyone know how to solve this? I feel really stupid.

P.S. How do you deal with anger when doing a maths question?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that might work. First of all I am assuming that you are referring the field with $p$ elements (I would recommend you use the notation $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ and not $\mathbb{Z}_p$ in the future).

Try viewing $A$ as a map from $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^n \to (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^m$ and try to see how many elements are there in a subspace of given dimension. Now try to compute the number of elements in the solution space of the system using the rank nullity theorem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: A map is just another word for a function, in this case a linear transformation.